# Why is Jason Stackhouse so submissive at the end of season 6?

Tags: true-blood

Is there an explanation of why Jason Stackhouse is so submissive towards the female vampire that "claimed" him in episode seven and through the last episode of the season?

It seems out of character: he stays with her after they get out and lets her feed on him.

Could it just be he fell in love? Or maybe Stockholm syndrome but that seems too easy.

Comment: well he stays with her after they get out and lets her feed on him, after asking the question I kinda thought it could just be he fell in love or maybe Stockholm syndrome but that seemed to easy

Answer (score 2):

All through S6 of True Blood, Jason is dealing with feelings of remorse/regret about his sexual behavior that he's kept up all his life.

We learn early on in the season that he was apparently the willing victim of sexual abuse by an older female teacher, and he also talks about how he's used sex all his life to hide his true feelings.  Even worse, his giving in to his baser sexual urges absolutely destroyed his friendship with Hoyt, and that loss hurt him deeply, and he accepts the guilt of being the cause.

Now he's involved in a relationship with a **much** older woman who, due to her old school Catholic upbringing, holds sexual intercourse at an extremely high value (although other forms of fooling around seem to be ok).  This is a new experience for Jason, who's always seen sex as cheap fun without much meaning behind it, and has grown to regret it.

So - speculatively speaking, it seems quite reasonable that while Jason is eager to actually consummate the relationship, he's fascinated by having to wait - something he's probably never had to do before.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a mix between love, the effects from her blood and her abstinence combined with Jason's libido. He is simply horny and used to having girls available. She is different.

Comment: Is this just your opinion?